# Don't fail if pattern is not found

Tags: search, error

I have the following autocmd to search for function definitions in C files.

```
autocmd Filetype c,cpp execute "nnoremap ]m /\\v^[^=]*(([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]+)|(operator .*))\\(.*\\)( const|:)?( \\{)?$\<cr>:nohl\<cr>"
```

As I have `incsearch` defined, it will hightlight all the matches, why I can `:nohl` at the end.
However the search fails if there are no matches found, and the :nohl is not executed in this case

This would be fine, if the search didn't fail and throw an error if it found nothing, but would just didn't change the cursor (which it should).

Comment: use either `:try|:catch|:finally` clause (which would be hard in your case, or wrap the optional part into an `:exe` command and add the `:nohl` at the end. That should work nomatter whether the `:exe` returns an error or not. BTW: Your mapping is too complex.

Comment: Why *too complex*? I guess regexes are always complex.

Comment: it's not easily understandable. 1) you don't need the `:exe` part 2) your pattern needs to be double escaped because of double quotes That is what I call too complex

Answer (score 4):

Here's a mapping that won't change the last search register or print errors:

```
nnoremap <expr> ]m filter([search('pattern', 'nW'), line('.')], 'v:val')[0].'G'
```

`filter()` takes a list of items and returns a list containing the ones that are satisfied by the second argument.  It's using a simple `'v:val'` to evaluate the item as a boolean.  Note that it's using the first item from the filtered list: `filter(...)[0].'G'`.

Since `search()` returns a matching line number on success, it will be the first item in that list.  If there is no match, it'll return `0` and won't be in the filtered list.  As a fallback, the current line number is used.

If the pattern matches on line `15` the map expression will return `15G` which jumps to that line.  Since `G` is a jump motion, the jump list will be updated.

It can work in the opposite direction by adding the `b` flag to the search flags:

```
nnoremap <expr> [m filter([search('pattern', 'bnW'), line('.')], 'v:val')[0].'G'
```

If you wanted it to wrap around the buffer, you could remove the `W` flag.

A real example of this working:

```
augroup vimrc_fugitive
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType gitcommit
        \ nnoremap <expr><buffer> } filter([search('\%(\_^#\?\s*\_$\)\\|\%$', 'nW'), line('$')], 'v:val')[0].'G' |
        \ nnoremap <expr><buffer> { max([1, search('\%(\_^#\?\s*\_$\)\\|\%^', 'nbW')]).'G'
augroup END
```

This is what I'm using to get paragraph motions back in [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)